# Codeigniter Unable to load the requested file, only when hosted

Tags: php, codeigniter, fullcalendar, hosting

I'm trying to implement Fullcalendar into my web app. 
Since I want 2 different calendars to work differently, I have 2 folders of fullcalendar named differently.

Both calendars work perfectly locally.
However, once I host the app lively, it gives me an error message saying

"Unable to load the requested file: fullcalendar.php" ( for one of the calendar only )

Here is my controller

```
function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('fullcalendar');
 }
```

and I do have [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcbbz.png)

fullcalendar.php as well. I have also set the base_url correctly.
I'm not quite sure what I'm missing because that error message is all I get.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You need to share some more code that at least allows us to try and figure out what  you're doing

Comment: Sounds like maybe you forgot to upload that file, or the permissions are wrong, or it's in the wrong location. As Javier says, it's pretty much impossible to tell without more info.

Comment: Apparently file names become case-sensitive once it is on live server. Also for this case, it only found the right file when its filename starts with a capital letter - Fullcalendar

Comment: "Apparently file names become case-sensitive once it is on live server" ...by any chance did you develop it on Windows and then deploy it to a Linux server? filenames etc are case-sensitive in Linux/Unix/MacOS but not in Windows. If that's your situation then, if you possibly can, it's better to develop on the same environment where you intend to deploy, then you don't have unexpected mistakes in the environment like this one. Maybe use a virtual machine, or dual boot. Or at least have a staging server with the same environment as live so you can try things.